# Laravel 5: How to get list of Parameters in Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I retrive list of `route` parameters in Middleware, tried multiple ways but always end with Error or empty result:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->route()->parameter('page');           //Call to a member function parameter() on null
    $request->route()->parameters();                //Call to a member function parameters() on null
    Request::capture()->getParameter('page');       //Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::getParameter()

    Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('page'); //Call to a member function getParameter() on null
    Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameters();      //Call to a member function getParameters() on null
    Route::getParameter('page');                    //Method getParameter does not exist.
}
```

Is there a way to get list of parameters in Middleware?
thanks,

Update: (add Route)

```
Route::get('test/{page}', array('uses'=>'test@test'));
```

Laravel version: 5.1.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NULL` value because you defined your middleware as global and global middleware run before the route is resolved.

If you need access to route parameters, use your middleware as route middleware in `App\Http\Kernel::$routeMiddleware` :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'my.middleware' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
     ],
];
```

[Proposals to change this behavior have been rejected by the Laravel maintainers due to architectural concerns.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9708)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request()` global helper:

```
request()->route('page');
```

Comment: use `request()->route('page');` return empty

Comment: controller: Route::get('test/{page}', array('uses'=>'test@test'));

Comment: Aren't you supposed to get data out of the `Request` class?  `request()->page` should do the trick.

Comment: @user3158900 still empty when print `request()->page`

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->route()->parameters();
```

Comment: Call to a member function parameters() on null

Comment: It means that something is wrong with your $request. As what you need is in $request->route()->parameters();

Comment: It seems some parts of request not instantiated yet, it works fine in the controllers