# Get Laravel Dynamic Route parameter in middleware

Tags: routes, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

We built a CMS using Laravel 5.6. We made various dynamic routes like below:

```
route::get('taxonomy/{taxonomy?}', 'TaxonomyController@list')->middleware('auth');
```

With this single route we can access unlimited number of registered Taxonomies, like:

```
http://example.com/taxonomy/category
http://example.com/taxonomy/tag
...
```

So, the taxonomy parameter is a variable thing in our routes.

Now we made a middleware to permit users according to their granted permissions. With our middleware the previous route would be:

```
route::get('taxonomy/{taxonomy?}', 'TaxonomyController@list')->middleware('auth', 'permissions:manage_{taxonomy?}');
```

And that's where the problem lies. We can't get that variable parameter into  the middleware parameter. We need this because the users can have permission to `category`, but can' have permission to `tag`. But with this route the user can't get access to either of the taxonomies. The whole route get blocked.

O, we tried with double quotes too:

```
route::get('taxonomy/{taxonomy?}', 'TaxonomyController@list')->middleware('auth', "permissions:manage_{taxonomy?}");
```

Is there any way we can pass dynamic route variables to middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revising [the Question by @mwafi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42009054/1743124) we've came into a solution for our case:

We're passing route permissions like below:

```
route::get('taxonomy/{taxonomy?}', 'TaxonomyController@list')->middleware('auth', 'permissions:manage_{parameter}');
```

And handling the permissions in the middleware like below:

```
<?php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $caps) {
    $current_args = $request->route()->parameters();
    // array_shift() is enough as we are passing a single parameter only.
    $current_parameter = array_shift($current_args);

    if (strpos($caps, '{parameter}') !== false) {
        // here the $caps become 'manage_{taxonomy}'
        $caps = str_replace( '{parameter}', $current_parameter, $caps );
    }

    // hasUserCap() - custom method to check user capability.
    if( hasUserCap( $caps, $request->user()->id ) ) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```